# PHP mailer not works

Tags: php, smtp

I want to make a mail system in php. 
This Code is works on a Local server. 
But,Its not working in a Live server !

thats error :

2018-09-22 14:29:49 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Thats My Code :

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;


$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                               

$mail->isSMTP();            

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          

$mail->Username = "mygmail@gmail.com";                 
$mail->Password = "mypassword";                           

$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           

$mail->Port = 587;                                   

$mail->From = "mygmail@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Full Name";

$mail->addAddress("mygmail@gmail.com", "Recepient Name");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your "live-Server" allows to send mails ?

Comment: Iam a beginer of php...Can you tell how can i check it ??

Comment: Consult your hosting provider on firewall issues. Use the CLI to test at least if pingable / or nmap to verify if smtp.gmail.com port 587 is reachable.

Comment: Also `SMTPDebug = 4`

Comment: Thanks  BlackNetworkBit & mario too.